# jQuery - way to find if form field is focused

Tags: jquery

Is there a way in jQuery to find out, if form filed is focused?

Like

```
if $('#id_here input[type=text]:focus'){ do this } else { }
```

?

Cheers, mart

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Use [`focus`](http://api.jquery.com/focus/) and [`blur`](http://api.jquery.com/blur/) event handlers:

```
$("#id_here input:text").focus(function(e) {
    // I am in focus, do something
    alert("I am a " + e.target.tagName);
}).blur(function(e) {
    // I have lost focus, do something else
});
```